# Конфликт фрагмента и активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Пытаюсь во **фрагменте** написать следующее:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Ошибка предсказуема, так как подобное я прописываю во фрагменте, а не в *активити* - *cannot be applied*, но решение данной проблемы не нахожу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно из описания в чем именно проблема...
Но ты можешь попробовать так:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```